# How do i get line number information for Chicken scheme errors

Tags: debugging, scheme, chicken-scheme

I am trying to isolate the cause of an error. The interpreter give "bad argument type" and a call history of 16 identical lines: `<eval> [procedure name] (sexpr)`. However, this procedure is call from many different places in the program. Is there a way to find out which one of these locations is the source of the problem without going thru the time consuming process of putting `print` calls in front of each and every possible candidate?

Comment: Not sure there are many Chicken users here. Did you try on their mailing list? it's quite active.

Comment: I might try that route, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [debug egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/debug) and change your procedure to first call **trace**.
Otherwise you could try and compile it with

```
csc --debug 2 <foo.scm>
```

Comment: Interesting, is there a corresponding option for `csi`?

Comment: none that i know of, but calling debug/trace is essentially the same.

Comment: Thanks, I guess calling that with `&& ./foo` is just as good.